# How to open a DialogFragment by clicking on a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, android-dialogfragment

I have a `MainActivity` like this one below:

[image]

My question is how to open a `DialogFragment` clicking on the `TextView` "click HERE to give a name to the task" placed next to "play" button.

Here is the code of my `TextView`:

```
TextView buttonView = new TextView(this);
buttonView.setHint("click HERE to give a name to the task");
buttonView.setX(50);
buttonView.setY(50);
```

and the code of the `DialogFragent`:

```
public class ButtonNameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private IFragment iButNamFrag;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder setButNameAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        setButNameAlert.setTitle("Set Task name");

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        setButNameAlert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_name_fragment, null))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Implement dialogPositiveClick

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.undo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Implement dialogNegativeClick 

                }
            });

        return setButNameAlert.create();

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        iButNamFrag = (IFragment) activity;
    }

}
```

and here is the interface:

```
public interface IFragment {

    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
    public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `onClickListener` to any view in Android and then perform any behavior you would like

```
buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Create new DiaglogFragment and display it
    }
};
```

This is the same method used for any kind of button pressing. There are plenty of other answers already out on StackOverflow with further examples of this. If you need more information on tap recognition or displaying fragments, a quick search will find it on Stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment frag = new ButtonNameDialogFragment();
            frag.show(*context*, ButtonNameDialogFragment.class.getCanonicalName());
        }
    });
```